# Geometry Nodes: Mesh or Polygon parenting face to another face (visually)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I was wondering what would be the best way with Geometry Nodes to achieve this effect below in the image, if we had only 3 faces of geometry. Of course the intention eventually is that there would be thousands and the faces were parented to each other.

Also the timing is crucial, it wouldn't look nice if all the faces curl up at the same time.

I tried to understand/copy the node network of this wonderful video, but it doesn't reveal all the group nodes so that didn't work out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcg5X18SYuo

(EDIT: Ah! there's a newer one. I'll try if I can make a sense of it: https://youtu.be/vSr6yUBs8tY?si=iAL8EL1K7tfBF-QD )

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Managed to follow the video tutorial above and got something done.

It handles nicely the visually looking 'parenting', but sadly it's too complicated for me to understand fully.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]